# Convert time to datatime format, keeping "AM/PM"

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series

There is 'AM' in my 'Time' column. So can I covert it to datetime format without removing 'AM'.
This is my dataset:

```
Time        Avg wind speed   Measured power production
12:00:00 AM     0.00             0.049645
12:15:00 AM     1.73             1.774442
12:30:00 AM     1.74             1.765177
12:45:00 AM     1.37             1.126741
```

I was going to use `data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')` to convert it but the 'AM' is troubling me.

Is there anyway to convert it directly to datatime? OR Should I just remove 'AM' and then use the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%I` for hours in 12H format and `%p` for match `AM/PM`:

```
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format='%I:%M:%S %p')
```